# Is there a standard reference where entropy is set equal to zero in property tables?

Tags: entropy, units, ideal-gas

For practical considerations, it seems that entropy is only meaningful as a difference between states, like $\Delta s$ going from state A to state B.  For an ideal gas, for instance, [standard formulas](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/therm/entropgas.html) give some infinities for entropy at absolute zero.

But we still tabulate values.  Looking at these tables, I see the s=0 point to be around -10 to -5 degrees C [for air](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/moist-air-properties-d_1256.html).  This doesn't seem to be consistent with other substances (notable steam tables).  Is there a commonly accepted rule about where entropy to zero.  While that point is arbitrary physically, different steam tables would need to use the same offset to be compatible among each other.  I'm interested to know if there's a standard rule for this.  Particularly for ideal gases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you cite is a table for moist air.  There is a convention for moist air entropy built from dry air entropy being 0 at T = 273.15K and P = 101325Pa, and liquid water entropy being 0 at its triple point.  See the page numbered 47 of this NIST document:

http://www.nist.gov/calibrations/upload/5241.pdf

Steam tables also use the standard that liquid water at the triple point has 0 entropy.

Another, more absolute, standard is to take the entropy of all pure crystalline substances to be zero at absolute zero.

For aqueous ions, the entropy of aqueous H+ is usually taken to be 0.